# how to filter partial data in one column

Tags: sql-server-2008

i hope you guys can help me with my query.  Im using  my sql database 2008.
I have to get the partial data from one column which contains so many data. This goes like this. 
in finaldiagcode column with so many codes like this (AO9, E86.1 E10.1), i need to get data that matches to E10.1

I have tried to use [] in my query but it does not work.

thank you and hope you can help me.

Comment: Please show your table schema, example data, what you ahve tried and what you expect. Or even better, create an example here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
select finaldiagcode from yourtable where finaldiagcode like 'E10.1%'
```